# Smudge Shader GLSL

Tags: glsl, shader, sfml, visual-effects

So I was playing around with some shaders.
I have texture like this:

[image]

I was wondering if there is any way I can kinda "smudge" it something like this:

[image]

I tried with gaussian blur but the results were really bad. It only made black edges smoother, any ideas?

Comment: Firstly, you can scale down the texture as really small, then apply smooth, scale up again, and draw the screen. That should be work. But I'm not sure that gives your expectation like above.

Comment: First distort the lookup coordinates with a medium frequency noise then apply a slight blur with a varying(use noise again) kernel footprint(=size).